# PrimeFaces dialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf, primefaces

Please Help me!I try to display the primefaces dialog but after clicking on the button nothing is displayed. Noted that I use bootstrap in my codes and my IDE is eclipse with JSF2.2.

```
<div class="panel-body">
<h:form id="roleform">
    <p:growl id="rolemsgs" showDetail="true" />
<p:dataTable id="basicDT" var="role" value="#{roleBean.listRole}">
    <f:facet name="header">Liste Role</f:facet>
    <p:column headerText="ID">
        <h:outputText value="#{role.idRole}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Nom Role">
        <h:outputText value="#{role.nomRole}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center">
        <p:commandButton ajax="true" update=":roleform:dialogform:roleDetail" oncomplete="PF(roleDialog).show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="View">            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{role}" target="#{roleBean.selectRole}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<p:dialog header="Role Info" widgetVar="roleDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
    <h:form id="dialogform">
        <p:outputPanel id="roleDetail" style="text-align:center;">
            <p:panelGrid  columns="2" columnClasses="label,value">
                <f:facet name="header">Infos Role</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="ID :" />
                <h:outputText value="#{roleBean.selectRole.idRole}" />

                <h:outputText value="Nom Role :" />
                <h:outputText value="#{roleBean.selectRole.nomRole}" />
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Nesting forms is never a good idea. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element

Answer (score 2):

Try enclosing your widget name with single quotes

```
oncomplete="PF('roleDialog').show();"
```

Also when debugging jsf and primefaces, try to use your browser inspector and check the console. Usually primefaces related problem will show the javascript error there.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your help. I have applied your recommendations but I forgot to inform you that I also use JQuery which creates a conflict with the PF functions. I still can not find a solution on my side. Please help me if you have any ideas

Comment: jquery should work with primefaces. try to update your post with the jquery script you have.

Comment: Hello, I have not yet written a script personally. I use dropdown and other bootstrap scripts for drop-down menus

Comment: I've tested your code and my answer should solve it unless there are any other errors in your server log and in the browser console. You should check if there are any and update your post.

Answer (score 0):

You should process the button and also add the quotation marks. the default value for ajax is true so you don't have to declare the attribute.

```
<p:commandButton process="@this" update=":roleform:dialogform:roleDetail" 
oncomplete="PF('roleDialog').show()" icon="ui-icon-search" value="View">
     <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{role}" target="{roleBean.selectRole}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/commandButton.xhtml